# Rails Joins not working in Serializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, serialization

I am quite new to building APIs in rails, I am currently in a situation where I need to use the current active record serializer object and one another object I passed to it using scope. With these objects I need to run a Join(Active Record Query Interface) from the serializer def to find out a particular data.

While the same query run quite good in the rails console, trying to execute it in serializer throws "no such method error".

```
Section.joins(question_papers_sections: :questions).where('questions.id = object.id AND question_papers_sections.question_paper_id = current_exam_candidate.exam.question_paper.id')
```

I can access the Section object here (tried using binding.pry), the serializer object is also accessible, and current_exam_candidate is accessible too.

Comment: Please ask for the model  structure etc in case it's required, hopefully as per me It's probably not  a requirement. Also, please suggest me if theirs another way of doing it, like may be passing the object value to a helper method and running the join query there. Please do help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a method in the base controller of your API if any, or define a method in the relative model. You should also change your query a bit, I am giving an example

example: In your controller

```
class Api::BaseController < ActionController::Base

  serialization_scope :view_context

  def find_question_section(object)
    section = Section.joins(question_papers_sections: :questions).where("questions.id = ? AND question_papers_sections.question_paper_id = ? ", object.id, current_exam_candidate.exam.question_paper.id).last
  end
end
```

And in your serializer

```
delegate :find_question_section , to: :scope 
find_question_section(object)
```